# Sample code for adding data and querying from Private Collection

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I have successfully added a Private Data Collection into my network. Following is the procedure I followed. I want Org1 and Org3 on this collection. I have following `collection_config.json`

```
[
 {
    "name": "collectionOrg1Org3",
    "policy": "OR('Org1MSP.member', 'Org3MSP.member')",
    "requiredPeerCount": 0,
    "maxPeerCount": 3,
    "blockToLive":1000000,
    "memberOnlyRead": true
 }
]
```

Then I added this collection when I am initiating the chain code on the collection. I used `collections-config` parameter as follows.

```
 docker exec \
      -e CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP \
      -e CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=${Org1_MSPCONFIGPATH} \
      cli \
      peer chaincode instantiate \
        -o orderer.bc4scm.de:7050 \
        -C mychannel \
        -n scmlogic \
        -l "$CC_RUNTIME_LANGUAGE" \
        -v 1.0 \
        -c '{"Args":[]}' \
        -P "OR('Org1MSP.member','Org3MSP.member')" \
        --tls \
        --cafile ${ORDERER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE} \
        --peerAddresses peer0.org1.bc4scm.de:7051 \
        --tlsRootCertFiles ${Org1_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE} \
        --collections-config ${CC_SRC_PATH}/collection_config.json
```

It didn't give me any error. So I hope it is added properly.

Next task is adding data into this collection by an authorized peer and query data from the collection. I was looking for a sample code I can refer to do this, but I couldn't find one written in Nodejs. Official documentation provides an [example](https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/tutorial-private-data.html) using typescript but not on javascript. I have the following questions.

1. Should I change anything in the chain code to support this new collection? I hope not. Please correct me if I am wrong.
2. How can I implement adding data and querying logic in my nodejs client app to do this?

I am using the following code to add data into a channel by Org1 user which is working properly. Please provide me the updates I should make.

```
'use strict';

const { FileSystemWallet, Gateway } = require('fabric-network');
const path = require('path');

const ccpPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..', 'network', 'connection-org1.json');

async function main() {
    try {

        const walletPath = path.join(process.cwd(), 'wallet');
        const wallet = new FileSystemWallet(walletPath);
        console.log(`Wallet path: ${walletPath}`);

        // Check to see if we've already enrolled the user.
        const userExists = await wallet.exists('user1');
        if (!userExists) {
            console.log('An identity for the user "user1" does not exist in the wallet');
            console.log('Run the registerUser.js application before retrying');
            return;
        }

        // Create a new gateway for connecting to our peer node.
        const gateway = new Gateway();
        await gateway.connect(ccpPath, { wallet, identity: 'user1', discovery: { enabled: true, asLocalhost: true } });

        // Get the network (channel) our contract is deployed to.
        const network = await gateway.getNetwork('iboretailerchannel');

        // Get the contract from the network.
        const contract = network.getContract('scmlogic');

        // Submit the specified transaction.
        // createCar transaction - requires 5 argument, ex: ('createCar', 'CAR12', 'Honda', 'Accord', 'Black', 'Tom')
        // changeCarOwner transaction - requires 2 args , ex: ('changeCarOwner', 'CAR10', 'Dave')
        await contract.submitTransaction('createCar', 'CAR12', 'Honda', 'Accord', 'Black', 'Tom');
        console.log('Transaction has been submitted');

        // Disconnect from the gateway.
        await gateway.disconnect();

    } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Failed to submit transaction: ${error}`);
        process.exit(1);
    }
}

main();
```

and following is my client code for querying data from a user from Org3

```
'use strict';

const { FileSystemWallet, Gateway } = require('fabric-network');
const path = require('path');

const ccpPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..', 'network', 'connection-org3.json');

async function main() {
    try {
        let user = 'user4';
        // Create a new file system based wallet for managing identities.
        const walletPath = path.join(process.cwd(), 'wallet');
        const wallet = new FileSystemWallet(walletPath);
        console.log(`Wallet path: ${walletPath}`);


        // Check to see if we've already enrolled the user.
        const userExists = await wallet.exists(user);
        if (!userExists) {
            console.log('An identity for the user ' + user + ' does not exist in the wallet');
            console.log('Run the registerUser.js application before retrying');
            return;
        }

        const gateway = new Gateway();

        await gateway.connect(ccpPath, { wallet, identity: user, discovery: { enabled: true, asLocalhost: true } });


        const result = await contract.evaluateTransaction('queryAllCars','BR0');

        console.log(`Transaction has been evaluated, result is: ${result.toString()}`);

    } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Failed to evaluate transaction: ${error}`);
        process.exit(1);
    }
}

main();
```

I am not using any biolerplate.

Appreciate your inputs on this issue. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I change anything in the chain code to support this new
>   collection? I hope not. Please correct me if I am wrong.

From the above Invoke/query code snippets it seems like the Collection Name is not passed as a parameter.

So I think you might have hard coded the collection name in chaincode itself on the stub functions **PutPrivateData** and **getPrivateData**.

So yes you have to edit the chaincode again and again for the new collections you add.
Solution for this is just pass the collection name with rest of the parameters/args from the client app.

> How can I implement adding data and querying logic in my nodejs client
>   app to do this?

You just have to add the **collection name** parameter in the **submitTransaction** and **evaluateTransaction** with rest of the parameters/args,rest of the code remains the same.

if any doubts do comment.